# Use of multi outlet adapter with dehumidifier

Tags: electrical

Is it safe to use a multi outlet adapter with dehumidifier?    And if not, why?   Have only one outlet near the dehumidifier and won’t use extension cord as not recommended.  Thank you.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using an extension cord as long as the cord has large enough wires.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. How many watts is the dehumidifier? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Feel free to edit your question to give specifics on the model of the dehumidifier if you want additional guidance on what extension cord specifications you need to be aware of.

Comment: And some multi outlet adapters are better than others. Please describe the one you're interested in using.